# Get an employees start and end date for each position from an employee history table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to have in one sql query an output in one line that has the start date and end date of each position for an employee.

Current table structure is:

```
| EMP_ID | SYST_LOGIN | TEAM | POSITION | LOCATION | START_DATE | END_DATE |
|--------|------------|------|----------|----------|------------|----------|
| 123456 | FNAM.LNAM  | A    | POS1     | LOC1     | 01-JAN-17  | 31-JAN-17|
| 123456 | FNAM.LNAM  | A    | POS1     | LOC2     | 01-FEB-17  | 15-FEB-17|
| 123456 | FNAM.LNAM  | B    | POS1     | LOC2     | 16-FEB-17  | 15-MAR-17|
| 123465 | FNAM.LNAM  | C    | POS2     | LOC2     | 16-MAR-17  | NULL     |
```

I need the out put to be:

```
| EMP_ID | SYST_LOGIN | POSITION | LOCATION | START_DATE | END_DATE  |
|--------|------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------|
| 123456 | FNAM.LNAM  | POS1     | LOC2     | 01-JAN-17  | 15-MAR-17 |
| 123465 | FNAM.LNAM  | POS2     | LOC2     | 16-MAR-17  | NULL      |
```

A new employee table was built and the business is requested that all changes to an employee create a new record in the table opposed to just updating the new location.  So now I want to look at an employees position and know the start date and end date.  Thank you for your help.

Gordon Linoff's query below worked for this.

****Updated second scenario that I ran into****

```
| EMP_ID | SYST_LOGIN | TEAM | POSITION | LOCATION | START_DATE | END_DATE |
|--------|------------|------|----------|----------|------------|----------|
| 123456 | FNAM.LNAM  | A    | POS1     | LOC1     | 01-JAN-17  | 31-JAN-17|
| 123456 | FNAM.LNAM  | A    | POS1     | LOC2     | 01-FEB-17  | 15-FEB-17|
| 123456 | FNAM.LNAM  | B    | POS1     | LOC2     | 16-FEB-17  | NULL     |
```

Using Gordon Linoff's query he gave below:

select EMP_ID, SYST_LOGIN, POSITION, LOCATION,
       min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
from t
group by EMP_ID, SYST_LOGIN, POSITION, LOCATION

Using this I get the following results:

```
 | EMP_ID | SYST_LOGIN | POSITION | LOCATION | START_DATE | END_DATE  |
 |--------|------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------|
 | 123456 | FNAM.LNAM  | POS1     | LOC2     | 01-JAN-17  | 15-FEB-17 |
```

Due to the fact the employee is still active the END_DATE on the last record is NULL and is not used when using max(END_DATE).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the SQL code you have so far.

Comment: You can add `coalesce(END_DATE, DATE '9999-12-31)` to the Gordon's query to handle the new case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no gaps, then this is just aggregation:

```
select EMP_ID, SYST_LOGIN, POSITION, LOCATION,
       min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
from t
group by EMP_ID, SYST_LOGIN, POSITION, LOCATION;
```

Comment: So you are right , assuming no gaps and no overlap there are no breaks this works.  I have one other scenario that this does not work for and added it above if you would be able to look at it.  Thank you for responding!! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like yours and this is my approach by using laravel and its scope..

```
    public function scopeEmploye_Location_By_Year_Month($query, $year, $month)
    {
        $from = date($year . '-' . $month . '-' . '01');
        $to = date($year . '-' . $month . '-' . 't');

        return $query->where(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->where('START_DATE', '<=', $from)->where('END_DATE', '>=', $from);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->where('START_DATE', '<=', $to)->where('END_DATE', '>=', $to);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->where('START_DATE', '>=', $from)->where('END_DATE', '<=', $to);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->where('START_DATE', '<=', $from)->where('END_DATE', '=', null);

        });
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.